# Android get xhdpi icon from ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo

Tags: android, icons, drawable, dpi

I'm successfully getting a recent app's icon using this code:

```
//app is an ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo
//image is an ImageView
ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(app.topActivity.getPackageName(), 0);
Drawable d = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
image.setImageDrawable(d);
```

However the image displayed is only 48x48px. I'm guessing this is because my device is mdpi, however it's making the icons very blurry. Is there a way to always get the xhdpi icon, regardless of the devices display density? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get any other density icons out of packageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo); without some hacking. Either you would hack the device's reported screen DPI or somehow convince PackageManager that you have a xhdpi screen size (you can specify a Bitmap's density, but I don't know how you could pass that to PackageManager).

However there might be an easier way to get the xhdpi icon (and other DP icons as well). If you can get the application's apk to your computer and unzip it, you should find the res/drawable* folder(s) inside where you could get the icon from.
Though if you need xhdpi icons during your app runtime and for any app on the device, this sadly is not the solution to your problem. If the latter is the case, note also that not every app has xhdpi resources/icons.